# How to save a macro (for quickly printing a variable)?

Tags: vimrc, macro, register

I'm trying to create a macro for an action that I very frequently use in Python: printing a variable in a bright color so it can easily be found in the traces while debugging.

So lets say there's something like:

```
myfunctioncall(myvariable)
```

I want the macro to add:

```
print("\u001b[35m", myvariable, "\u001b[0m")
```

on the line below it. (assuming the cursor was anywhere in the word "myvariable")

I tried writing the macro by hand, but I quickly had to realize that I'm still too noobish for that. Instead I recorded the macro, and tried to save that by using the CTRL-R CTRL-R  method.

However, it appears for some reason the macro isn't properly "pasted" to my vimrc from the register. The `o`-register in code down below is directly recorded to the register. The `p`-register is the one that it got from the vimrc (after pasting from register).

```
  c  "o   yawA^Mprintf(<80>kb<80>kb("\u001b[35m", ^[<80><fd>apA, "\u001b[0m")^[<80><fd>a
  c  "p   yawA^Mprintf(<80>kb<80>kb("\u001b[35m", ^[<80>ýapA, "\u001b[0m")^[<80>ýa
```

As you can see, it is slightly different. `<fd>` has changed into `ý` for some reason. Anyone who can explain my why this is and how I can fix it?

(Ps: I know some of you will be tempted to just give me a working macro instead. Those answers are also welcome, but keep in mind that I did not use `O` on purpose, but instead used `A[ENTER]` so that the Python-indentation is retained.)

EDIT: I just noticed something else that's odd! In the macro snippets above it says print**f**, while if I use the macro it uses a regular print! This is so odd?

EDIT2: I didn't make it very clear, but the macro in register `p` does **not** work. This is what I get when using it:

```
printf(<U+0080>kb<U+0080>kb("\u001b[35m",
```

Comment: Somewhat related to the `^[<80><fd>` and `ý`: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/35207/18609 Also, the reason why you see `printf(` and the macro outputs `print(` is that the `printf(` is followed by two `<80>kb` which are backspaces, and then it picks up from the `("` part. One thing I didn't understand from your question is whether the second macro `"p` actually *works* or not... Yes, I see they show up differently (I assume that's the output of `:reg` correct?) but does `"p` actually *not* work? I'll take another look at the question a bit later, try to reproduce it... Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for the explanation about the f and the backspaces! That actually makes a lot of sense! Also thanks for the link. It gave me a lot of insight that I might be able to use in the future when making or editing my macro's.
I probably didn't make it clear enough in my Question, but no. The `p` macro doesn't work. It only produces half of what it's supposed to, and also inserts some command characters literally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`O` should work with python and keep the current indent level. You may want to look at your indention settings and/or ensure `filetype indent on`.

I set `filetype plugin indent on` in my `vimrc`. It is also set in `defaults.vim`

#### Whats the `<fd>`??

> As you can see, it is slightly different. `<fd>` has changed into ý for some reason. Anyone who can explain my why this is and how I can fix it?

As @filbranden mentioned `^[<80><fd>` is a [no op](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/35207/18609). In general Vim may detect/record more than you expect due to Vim's implementation and terminal behavior.

#### A macro who grew up to be a mapping

> I'm trying to create a macro for an action that I very frequently use in Python: printing a variable in a bright color so it can easily be found in the traces while debugging.

Macros are great and they are a good first start towards building a propper mapping. Replaying macros depend on registers which tend to be ephemeral. Mappings are a great way to store such commands for later.  They also use key-notation which is often easier to read and are not limited to only 26ish registers.

You could easily create a mapping for this following the same commands in your macro. I'm using `\p` as an example trigger for the mapping

```
nnoremap \p yawA<cr>print("\u001b[35m", <esc>pA, "\u001b[0m")<esc>
```

For more help see:

```
:h key-notation
:h map-overview
```

#### Problems

However, there are problems with this mapping which may not be apparent.

- It mutates the unnamed register. This might be surprising later on
- This is a python specific mapping which it not useful for other `'filetype'`'s (aka global mapping)

#### Side effects in your mappings

This mapping mutates the unnamed register `""`. This can be avoided a few different ways, but I am going to show you how to leverage `<cword>` which is the current word the cursor is on:

```
nnoremap \p "=[printf('print("\u001b[35m", %s, "\u001b[0m")', expand('<lt>cword>'))]<cr>]p
```

This mapping uses the expression register, `"=`, to evaluate a Vim expression which happens to be a `printf()` statement where we use the current word, `expand('<cword>')`. Wrap the expression in an array to force this to be line-wise and do a same indent-level put with `]p`

For more help see:

```
:h "=
:h expand()
:h printf()
:h ]p
:h <cword>
:h <lt>
:h key-notation
```

#### Local Mappings

Lets make this mapping only for `python` files by making it local to the `<buffer>`. We can do this two different ways: use an `autocmd` or use the after-director  (e.g. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`)

```
autocmd Filetype python nnoremap <buffer> \p "=[printf('print("\u001b[35m", %s, "\u001b[0m")', expand('<lt>cword>'))]<cr>]p
```

Or use the after-directory by putting a file here `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` and add the mapping:

```
nnoremap <buffer> \p "=[printf('print("\u001b[35m", %s, "\u001b[0m")', expand('<lt>cword>'))]<cr>]p
```

Using the after-directory tends to be my preference

For more help see:

```
:h :au
:h :map-local
:h after-directory
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for not only solving my problem, but also giving an in-depth explanation that even a rookie like me can understand! I wouldn't be able to create one myself yet I'm afraid, but thanks to your ELI5 explanation I think I understand what every part of the mapping does. 
About the indentation: My Vim already auto indents Python files, but if I exit insert mode (what my macro did, when it tried to paste) it deletes the indentation and goes back to the start of the line.

Comment: Extra question: let's say I want to make an identical command that inserts it on the line **above** it, instead of below it. For that I assume I need to use `P` instead of `p` at the end. But then how do I fix the indentation to not use the on of the current line, but 1 tabwidth less? Can I add an offset to `]`?

Comment: Nevermind that last question in comment. In most cases you will also want to be on the same indent when inserting it above the line. It's only when there's a conditional or loop that you would want to decrease the indentation, but I guess it's best to do that manually in those cases. 
Again, thanks a lot! I will wait the usual 24h before accepting the answer, but have an upvote in the meantime!

Comment: Just one thing: the filetype specific command does not work. (I initially thought it did, but that was still the previous mapping existing)

Comment: I have included the full after-directory path and have tested both ways. They do work. Please make sure you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your `~/.vim/vimrc`. You can verify by running `:filetype`, it should give you `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON   indent:ON`

Comment: I got them to work. Thanks a lot Peter! You've made me a little less Vim-green! :)