# Individual macros function but combined macros do not

Tags: macro

I am trying to brute-force the Caesar shift cipher in vim. I have recorded three macros f, a, and d where f copies the line and a applies a Caesar shift to all elements on the line by calling macro d which Caesar shifts a char. Both macros work fine individually, and when I spam @f@a on my keyboard, but when I create a new macro @f@a using any other register, the macro doesn't function properly, it doesn't create a new line and appears to only Caesar shift the current line.

This is my text file w/ macros#

```
# abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
# bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzaBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA

"brute-forcing Caesar shift cipher w/ vim macros

"input is given at bottom of file

"subroutines
""duplicate bottom line
call:f
yyp

""Caesar shift line
call:a
!!wc -c^M0Yuo^[<80>ýapa@d^[<80>ýa0"rDk@r

""Caesar shift character
call:d
mfyl3Gpif^[<80><fd>alajyl^[<80><fd>a0"sD1G@s`fvpl


hello world
```

Edit: the new macro I was referring to was @f@a. The key sequence @f@a works fine but @x where @x=@f@a where x is any register does not behave the same. Can anyone reproduce this behavior?

Edit: I have included macro d. Note: macro r is recorded in macro a. I understand the vim macros are incomprehensible but how could, even ignoring the macros, a key-sequence like @f@a be different than @x which has @f@a stored inside register x?

Comment: Could you clean up macro `a`? Also you appear to have two other non-mentioned macros, there: `@d` and `@r`. And can we see the problematic macro?

Comment: I will attempt to clear up the macro later but, when I write @f @a repeatedly both macros work perfectly fine. But do not work with @f@a recorded to any register. Even treating the macros as a black box, this should not be possible. Can any one reproduce this issue by copying the macros?

Comment: "Can any one reproduce this issue by copying the macros?" That's precisely why I asked you to clean up your macro. And again, your macro `a` appears to be using two other macros `@d` and `@r` that you didn't provide. How do you expect us to reproduce your issue with what you give?

Comment: I have included macro d, macro r is recorded in macro a using "rD

Comment: Still no cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question [is *extremely*](http://whileyouweregone.co.uk/vimlife/) my [bag](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=this%20is%20my%20bag).

### What's going wrong

The problem with your macro is your use of [`u`](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#u). When you're recording the macro, it undoes the most recent change. But when you're playing back the macro, it undoes *all the edits so far in the macro playback*. (I presume this is a side-effect of the implementation of the essential behaviour that using it *after* playing back the macro [undoes the entire invocation](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#undo-blocks).)

So during the playback of macro `"a`, it just undoes the changes you made to the new line. But during the playback of your combined macro `"x` it undoes those changes *and* the duplication of the line made by macro `"f`.

### How to fix it

There's many possible fixes for this, but the one I ended up implementing was to replace this:

```
0Yuo^[<80>ýapa

0Y              # yank character count
  u             # undo (INTENDED TO revert to input text: broken)
   o            # start a new line below
    ^[<80>ýa    # exit insert mode (i.e. press <Esc>)
            p   # paste the character count on the new line
             a  # enter insert mode (at the end of the line)
```

With this:

```
         k@fjA

         k      # move up, (leaving the character count in the buffer)
          @f    # make a new copy of the input text
            j   # move back down to the line containing the character count
             A  # enter insert mode at the end of the line
```

## A complete solution

Here's a complete solution. I also converted the control characters into [string special characters](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) so it can be pasted into e.g. your vimrc, and replaced your use of `wc` in a [`!!` filter](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#filter) with some Vimscript called from [the expression register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote%3D), so it runs entirely inside Vim and on computers that don't happen to have `wc` available:

```
" caesar shift line
" broken a
let @a = "0y$cc\<C-R>=len(@0)\<CR>\<Esc>0Yuo\<Esc>\x80\xfdapa@d\<Esc>\x80\xfda0\"rDk@r"
" fixed a
let @a = "0y$cc\<C-R>=len(@0)\<CR>\<Esc>k@fjA@d\<Esc>\x80\xfda0\"rDk@r"

" caesar shift character
let @d = "mfyl3Gpif\<Esc>\x80\xfdalajyl\<Esc>\x80\xfda0\"sD1G@s`fvpl"

" duplicate and caesar shift
let @x = "@f@a"
```

### Extra credit

Your macros don't contain this issue, but there is another way that running two macros manually can behave differently to running them both from a third macro.

If the first macro aborts because of an error, then if you play them back manually the second one will carry on where the first left off. But when you run the third macro it will never run the second.

For a quick demonstration of this, try recording three macros by typing:

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>
<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

After recording the above, typing <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> will move to the bottom of the buffer and delete the bottom line, whereas typing <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will move to the bottom of the buffer but *won't* delete anything, even though `@c == "@a@b"`.

Comment: I guessed the problem was with the undo in the shower and was about to post my answer here but your answer is much better than I could write!
I couldn't even comprehend my own macro because of the weird characters either before the solution. I really appreciated the indented explanation diagrams.

Comment: @Progamer Glad I could help! I had a lot of fun figuring out how your macros worked and writing up my answer. Check out [filbranden's terrific answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/35207/343) for an explanation of the weird characters in the macros in your question.